# How do you sense if a key is pressed and held in Java?

Tags: java

I have been working on a singleplayer pong game in which you currently use the mouse to control the paddle. I have added key listeners to the frame, and you can move the paddle by hitting the 'a' and 'd' keys, but you cannot hold them down. Here is the code which I have now, and I'd appreciate any help that you can offer!

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Experiment extends JApplet {

    public static final int WIDTH = BallRoom.WIDTH;
    public static final int HEIGHT = BallRoom.HEIGHT;


    public PaintSurface canvas;

    public void init()
    {
        this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        canvas = new PaintSurface();
        this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        canvas.requestFocusInWindow();
        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(3);
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new AnimationThread(this), 0L, 20L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    }
}



class AnimationThread implements Runnable
{
    JApplet c;
    public AnimationThread(JApplet c)
    {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        c.repaint();
    }
}

class PaintSurface extends JComponent implements KeyListener
{
    int paddle_x = 0;
    int paddle_y = 360;
    public boolean aDown;
    public boolean dDown;


    int score = 0;
    float english = 1.0f;
    Ball ball;
    Color[] color = {Color.RED, Color.ORANGE, Color.MAGENTA, Color.ORANGE, Color.CYAN, Color.BLUE};
    boolean aheld = false;
    boolean dheld = false;

    int colorIndex;

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Pressed " + e.getKeyChar());
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getKeyChar() == 'd')
                paddle_x += 10;
            if (e.getKeyChar() == 'a')
                paddle_x -= 10;
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {

        }


    public PaintSurface()
    {
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter()
        {
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if (e.getX() - 30 - paddle_x > 5)
                    english = 1.5f; 
                else if (e.getX() - 30 - paddle_x < 5)
                    english = -1.5f;
                else
                    english = 1.0f;
                paddle_x = e.getX() - 30;
            }
        });

        addKeyListener(this);


        ball = new Ball(20);
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        Shape paddle = new Rectangle2D.Float(paddle_x, paddle_y, 60, 8);

        g2.setColor(color[colorIndex % 6]);

        if (ball.intersects(paddle_x, paddle_y, 60, 8) && ball.y_speed  > 0)
        {           
            ball.y_speed = -ball.y_speed * 1.1;
            ball.x_speed = ball.x_speed * 1.1;


            if (english != 1.0f)
            {
                colorIndex++;
            }
            score += Math.abs(ball.x_speed * 10);
        }

        if (ball.getY() + ball.getHeight() >= BallRoom.HEIGHT)
        {
            ball = new Ball(20);
            score -= 1000;
            colorIndex = 0;
        }
        ball.move();
        g2.fill(ball);

        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fill(paddle);
        g2.drawString("Score: " + score, 250, 20);
    }
}

class Ball extends Ellipse2D.Float{
    public double x_speed, y_speed;
    private int d;
    private int width = BallRoom.WIDTH;
    private int height = BallRoom.HEIGHT;

    public Ball(int diameter)
    {
        super((int) (Math.random() * (BallRoom.WIDTH - 20) + 1), 0, diameter, diameter);
        this.d = diameter;
        this.x_speed = (int) (Math.random() * 5) + 1;
        this.y_speed = (int) (Math.random() * 5) + 1;
    }

    public void move()
    {       
        if (super.x < 0 || super.x > width - d)
            x_speed = -x_speed;
        if (super.y < 0 || super.y > height - d)
            y_speed = -y_speed;

        super.x += x_speed;
        super.y += y_speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: The clue is in the keylistener; keyPressed & keyReleased.

Answer (score 0):

runningUse the following code for KeyPressed() and KeyReleased()

```
@Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getKeyChar() == 'd')
            dheld = true;
        if (e.getKeyChar() == 'a')
            aheld = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getKeyChar() == 'd')
            dheld = false;
        if (e.getKeyChar() == 'a')
            aheld = false;
    }
```

Then have method running on a timer that moves the paddle if dheld or aheld are true.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't seem to get it to work. I try to make it so that it moves the paddle when either aheld or dheld is true, but it doesn't actually move the paddle.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by a method running on a timer?

Comment: Use a [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and an ActionListener.